# Loading Exoplayer subtitles into a custom component

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I'm using exoplayer (2.18.7) to play some audio clips that have subtitles if the user decides so.

I'm using the base ExoPlayer class implementation.

I set up the MediaItem and the SubtitleConfiguration just fine, and now I would like to hook up the subtitles to a custom compose component that will display the subtitles but I'm struggling to find a listener or something for this, something similar to `MediaPlayer` `onTimedTextListener`, that is called when it is time to show some new subtitle text.

The most similar thing I found was the `onCues` listener but it doesn't seem to work for this use case.

How can I get the current subtitles to be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

```
public MediaSource getTextSource(Uri subTitle) {      
    Format textFormat = new Format.Builder()
            .setSampleMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP)
            .setSelectionFlags(C.SELECTION_FLAG_DEFAULT)
            .build();

    MediaItem.SubtitleConfiguration subtitle = new MediaItem.SubtitleConfiguration.Builder(subTitle)
            .setMimeType(checkNotNull(textFormat.sampleMimeType))
            .setLanguage(textFormat.language)
            .setLabel(String.valueOf(subTitle).substring(String.valueOf(subTitle).lastIndexOf('/') + 1))
            .setSelectionFlags(textFormat.selectionFlags).build();

    DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory factory = new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
            .setAllowCrossProtocolRedirects(true)
            .setConnectTimeoutMs(50000)
            .setReadTimeoutMs(50000)
            .setTransferListener(new DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder(this).build());

    MediaSource textMediaSource = new SingleSampleMediaSource.Factory(new DefaultDataSource.Factory(this,
            factory))
            .createMediaSource(subtitle, C.TIME_UNSET);
    return textMediaSource;
}
```

then

```
MergingMediaSource mergingMediaSource = new MergingMediaSource(mediaSource, subtitleSource);
concatenatingMediaSource = new ConcatenatingMediaSource();
player.setMediaSource(concatenatingMediaSource);
```